# I always get: "Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.", when i use pip install, in spyder (python)

Tags: python, installation, pip, spyder

I always get:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

when I use `pip install` in spyder (python).

I reinstalled anaconda, and the problem is still there.
This message is for all the new packs I try to install. The message appears, and the libraries aren't installed.

Note: I restarted the kernel several times. And I have the last version of pypi pip.

```
pip install pandas
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

```
pip install selenium
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

```
pip install pip
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Comment: Are you using the Spyder standalone installer for Window or MacOS? If that is the case those ways of installation don't come with pip bundled so if you need to use packages outside the ones the installer comes you can check the doc page explaining what you will need to do: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer